# Permuting Pixels Within a Binary Mask with PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm completely stuck on this problem - I need to randomly permute the pixels within a circle on a 2D image. I need this for an experiment I am designing, where searching for this small scrambled circle will act as a low-level perceptual part of a task. It is important that the pixels come from the image itself rather than being random values to keep the image intensity uniform between the modified and unmodified images.

I don't really know Python well so my code so far is very hacky - I first open the image, and make sure it is RGB. I then make a deep copy (as I'll be modifying the original with the mask, but I still need the actual original pixel values). Then I draw a bright-red circle (255, 0, 0), and define the pix_mask as anywhere where the red is 255 (our stimuli are natural scenes and objects, so there shouldn't be any other places in the image with this). I then create a new mask image using the `pix_mask`, and multiply the mask by the copied image data to get the data inside the circle. Sounds a mess, but here are the results:

[image: Red dot I use to specify the position of the mask]

[image: Original image after multiplication by the binary mask]

And here is the code I'm using to do this:

```
def create_pixel_mask_images(image_fname: str):
    # Open the image which requires a scrambled dot. Add an alpha channel and make a copy of the data 
    image: JpegImage          = Image.open(image_fname)
    image                     = image.convert("RGB")
    image_copy                = image.copy()

    # Create the drawer and draw a filled red circle on the original image (255, 0, 0)
    image_draw                = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    image_draw.ellipse((150, 150, 250, 250), fill = "red")
    image.save("TEST_DOT.png")

    # Read the data from the copy and the now-modified original image into arrays
    image_arr: NumpyArray      = numpy.array(image)
    image_copy_arr: NumpyArray = numpy.array(image_copy)

    # Create a binary mask by testing for the red circle we drew on the original image (255 red)
    pix_mask: NumpyArray       = image_arr[:, :, 0] == 255

    # Invert the mask (i.e., everything outside of the dot is now white, and the dot black)
    # Write them out to file to error-check
    mask_image: PILImage         = Image.fromarray((pix_mask * 255).astype(numpy.uint8))
    image.convert("RGB")
    mask_image_inverse: PILImage = ImageOps.invert(mask_image)
    image.convert("RGB")
    pix_mask_inverse: NumpyArray = numpy.array(mask_image_inverse)

    # Read the inverted pixel mask as a numpy array. Multiply the unmodified image by both masks
    # in order to get the data both inside and outside of the mask
    inner_data = image_copy_arr * pix_mask[..., None]
    outer_data = image_copy_arr * pix_mask_inverse[..., None]

    # Create new images from the masked data
    inner_image: PILImage = Image.fromarray(inner_data.astype(numpy.uint8))
    outer_image: PILImage = Image.fromarray(outer_data.astype(numpy.uint8))
    outer_image           = ImageOps.invert(outer_image)

    # AS A CHECK multiply the inner- and outer-masked images together. We should get the original image back
    image_data = image.load()

        for y in range(image.size[1]):
            for x in range(image.size[0]):
                if image_data[x, y] == (255, 0, 0):
                    image_data[x, y] = (255, 255, 255)
    recombined_image = ImageChops.multiply(inner_image, outer_image)
    
    inner_image.save('INNER_DATA.png')
    
    mask_image.save('MASK.jpg')
    mask_image_inverse.save('MASK_INVERSE.jpg')
    recombined_image.save('RECOMBINATION_TEST.jpg')
```

You can see at the bottom I create a `recombined_image` by multiplying the `inner_image`, which is the data within the circle mask, and the `outer_image`, which is the rest of the data outside of the circle mask, together; however, I just end up the same image as the second picture here (just the data inside the circle).

I use the nested `for`-loop here to set any red pixels in the original image to white as if I left the region black I would lose the data there (checked the docs for `ImageChops.multiply()` - [Docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageChops.html)). I've also tried the `ImageChops.overlay()` function with the same result - all black except for the portion previously masked out.

So now, I have the masked image, which is great; however, I don't seem to be able to recombine this masked region with the original. Firstly, I need to be able to permute the data inside of the masked region anyway before doing this.

So far my solution seems like an absolute mess and I'm sure there must be a more straightforward/elegant way to achieve what I need. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: You don't really need so much manipulation.  Just convert the image to a numpy array, choose your circles, and so a bunch of random swaps inside the circle.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the comment - I thought this was a bit much, too. When you say "choose your circles", how do I do this on a Numpy array? Could you give me a brief example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this works for me.  My test image is about 2k x 1500, so I chose a circle near the center.  I just randomly choose 75,000 pairs within that circle and swap them.  The result looks like static, of course.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import math
import random

img = Image.open('Melody1.jpg')
img = np.asarray(img.getdata()).reshape(img.size[1],img.size[0],3)
print(img.shape)

center = (1000, 800)
radius = 150

for i in range(75000):
    r1 = radius * math.sqrt(random.random())
    t1 = random.random() * 2 * math.pi
    r2 = radius * math.sqrt(random.random())
    t2 = random.random() * 2 * math.pi

    x1 = int(center[0] + r1 * math.cos(t1))
    y1 = int(center[1] + r1 * math.sin(t1))
    x2 = int(center[0] + r2 * math.cos(t2))
    y2 = int(center[1] + r2 * math.sin(t2))

    img[x1,y1,:], img[x2,y2,:] = img[x2,y2,:], img[x1,y1,:]

print(img.shape)
outimg = Image.fromarray(img.astype(np.uint8))
outimg.save( 'other.jpg' )
```

Here's the resulting image.  You'd want to do more swaps to make it unrecognizable.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, the static effect is exactly what I was after! Seems like the maths solution wins again.